# ObservableCollection gets reset (item count 0) going between 2 views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I am very new to MVVM so hopefully this isnt a hard problem.

Basically I have two Views:-
 1. Holds a Data Grid which displays everything inside the ObservableCollection object
 2. The second view basically has two text boxes which adds to the ObservableCollection when the user presses OK on the form.

Bascially what I am doing is showing the 2nd view from the 1st view with a button click, button labelled "Add Project"

Then I enter the information I need to add to the ObservableCollection in the 2nd view. When I press OK on the form, It calls a method "AddMProduct" which basically adds a item to the collection inside the ViewModel.

But the problem is by doing this its creating a new ViewModel() object so therefore reinitialise the ObservableCollection. So therefore the collection gets reset back to zero.

So in the MVVM model, how do I basically retain the collection, between the 2 views and the ViewModel?

Thanks

------------------Code---------------

VIEW 1

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void btnAddProjectGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   // Open new window here to add a new project group
      AddProductGroup dlg = new AddProductGroup();
     dlg.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

VIEW 2

```
   ProductGroupBindable newProduct = new ProductGroupBindable();
    ProductsViewModel viewModel = null;

    public AddProductGroup()
    {
        viewModel = new ProductsViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        newProduct.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        newProduct.Name = txtName.Text;
        newProduct.Description = txtDescription.Text;

        viewModel.AddProduct(newProduct);
        this.Close();
    }
```

VIEWMODEL

```
class ProductsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable> m_ProductCollection;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable> ProductCollection
    {

        get
        {
            Test();
            return m_ProductCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ProductCollection = value;
        }

    }

    private void Test()
    {
        m_ProductCollection.Add(new ProductGroupBindable { Description = "etc", Name = "test12" });
    }

    public ProductsViewModel()
    {
        if (m_ProductCollection == null)
            ProductCollection = new ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable>();
    }


    public void AddProduct(ProductGroupBindable newProduct)
    {
        ProductCollection.Add(newProduct);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCollection");
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: @Tomtom would help wouldn't it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simple option to fix the problem. Create an overload constructor of the dialog view that accepts `ProductsViewModel` as parameter. With that you can pass existing viewmodel object from `MainWindow` to the dialog, hence avoid instantiating new empty viewmodel :

```
//in MainWindow
private void btnAddProjectGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Open new window here to add a new project group
    AddProductGroup dlg = new AddProductGroup(this.viewmodel);
    dlg.ShowDialog();
}


//in AddProductGroup :
public AddProductGroup(ProductsViewModel vm)
{
    viewModel = vm;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Ignore that comment, just found out that you need to put "public" in front of the class, why VS didnt do this for me, I dont know. I think this will work as I tried this earlier, will mark if so. thanks

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, however, do you know why looking at the code above why the datagrid wont update when the an item is added? I know the DataGrid binding is correct as the Test() method adds one and then it shows. 

Also the getter of the ObservableCollection is getting hit every time I do add a item.

Comment: Not sure, your code looks fine. How you bind DataGrid to ObservableCollection? Try to debug and see what actually happen at run-time.

Comment: I have used XAML to bind the grid.


Its strange as it worked when I had the code in the MainWindow, but now I have put the collection into a ViewModel, I cant add by the view dialog. 

However, one behaviour that seems strange is when the code hits the ProductCollection.Add, the code will go to the getter for the collection..Is this correct?

I have posted the question into a new thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882777/data-grid-not-updating-from-viewmodel

Thanks

Comment: I see, so you have DataContext setting in XAML, then how you passed the viewmodel to dialog view? Should've been this way: `AddProductGroup dlg = new AddProductGroup((ProductsViewModel )this.DataContext);` ?

Comment: About the getter being called, it is expected behavior. Your actual collection stored in `m_ProductCollection`, `ProductCollection` is just kind of "mediator" to the underlying collection

Comment: I didnt think you had to pass the viewmodel back to the view?

Hence why I have        

xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Importer.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <VM:ProductsViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

So the DataContext knows where the binding source is from...

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "pass the viewmodel *back* to the view". I meant when passing the viewmodel from main window to the dialog window, how you did it? Because the viewmodel in main window instantiated in XAML (XAML snippet in your comment above means: create new instance of VM and set window's DataContext to that instance).

Comment: I think I understand what you mean.. so what you are saying is I have instantiated the DataContext on initialise (via XAML) but this is reset or instantated when I create a new instance of new ProductViewModel?