# Data Grid not updating from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

Do you know why looking at the code in the XAML and ViewModel why a Data Grid wont update when the an item is added? I know the DataGrid binding is correct as will add an item if I add it by code, however I am adding a item via a view.

Also the getter of the ObservableCollection is getting hit every time I do add a item.

Thanks

------ Code ------

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Importer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Product Group" Height="350" Width="721"
        xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Importer.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <VM:ProductsViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0.4,0.4">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgGrid" ColumnWidth="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" Width="400" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="btnAddProjectGroup" Content="Add Project Group" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="btnAddProjectGroup_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VIEW 1 (that uses the XAML above)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
        ProductsViewModel m_VM = new ProductsViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {     
            InitializeComponent();
        }


      private void btnAddProjectGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
       // Open new window here to add a new project group
          AddProductGroup dlg = new AddProductGroup(m_VM);

         dlg.ShowDialog();
      }
   }
```

VIEW 2 - The view that passes the values to add to the collection

```
public partial class AddProductGroup : Window
    {
        ProductGroupBindable newProduct = new ProductGroupBindable();
        ProductsViewModel viewModel = null;

        public AddProductGroup(ProductsViewModel vm)
        {
            viewModel = vm;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            newProduct.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            newProduct.Name = txtName.Text;
            newProduct.Description = txtDescription.Text;

            viewModel.AddProduct(newProduct);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

VIEWMODEL

```
 private ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable> m_ProductCollection;


        public ProductsViewModel()
        {
            if (m_ProductCollection == null)
                m_ProductCollection = new ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable>();
        }


     public ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable> ProductCollection
        {

            get
            {
                return m_ProductCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                m_ProductCollection = value;
            }

        }

        private ObservableCollection<ProductGroupBindable> Test()
        {
            m_ProductCollection.Add(new ProductGroupBindable { Description = "etc", Name = "test12" });
            m_ProductCollection.Add(new ProductGroupBindable { Description = "etc", Name = "test123" });

            return ProductCollection;
        }

        public void AddProduct(ProductGroupBindable newProduct)
        {
            m_ProductCollection.Add(newProduct);
            //NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCollection");
        }
```

Comment: what do you do in `btnAddProjectGroup_Click`?

Comment: I will edit the post to show my 2 views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `DataContext` in XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:ProductsViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

and your dialog works on another instance of `ProductsViewModel` which you create in code:

```
ProductsViewModel m_VM = new ProductsViewModel();
```

Easiest workaround would be to pass `DataContext` to your `AddProductGroup` dialog:

```
AddProductGroup dlg = new AddProductGroup(this.DataContext as ProductsViewModel);
```

**EDIT**

or instead of setting `DataContext` in XAML do set it in code:

```
public MainWindow()
{     
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = m_VM;
}
```

Comment: Thank you dkozl, may I ask if this is a "hack" or considered to be how the MVVM works. I only been working on it for 1 day so am keen to try to use the MVVC way as much as possible from the off. Thanks again

Comment: Initializing `DataContext` in code is perfectly acceptable

Comment: Thank you, I know your not getting paid for this help but if you do see anything I could do different (Especially in the ViewModel) can you tell me?

However, I have used AddProductGroup dlg = new AddProductGroup(this.DataContext as ProductsViewModel); for the solution, cheers again!

Comment: Without framework like [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) or [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Caliburn.Micro) it would require additional work to do it different however if you want to learn MVVM try to write as much by yourself.

Comment: WPF is based on of few basic interfaces like [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) for view model, `INofityCollectionChanged` for collection (`ObservableCollection` implements that) and [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.icommand) for command binding. Look into command binding. For example `Button` has `Command` that you can bind to some `ICommand` in your view model to do some action. You can bind commands in WPF just like other properties

Comment: Don't work against WPF and don't process UI controls in code. Use bindings, triggers, templates and write as much UI code as you can in XAML and keep application logic in view model. Keep it separated.